# Create Regex Patterns

Tags: java, android, regex

How can I develop a mobile phone pattern in android in which:

1. It's length would be 8 digits
2. The first two digits should be 03 or 71 or 72 or 76 or 78

I created this but it's not working for the first two digits because I don't know how to do it :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}\\d{6}");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this pattern `(03|71|72|76|78)\d{6}`.